# Plotting histogram of Pandas Dataframe with its mean and standard deviation, getting ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of daterange as index and one column and 2192 rows. I am able to plot this dataframe on histogram but when I try to include mean and standard deviation of this dataframe on histogram I get a ValueError caused at these lines

```
#compute daily returns
daily_returns = stats.compute_daily_returns(df_btc)
#plotter.plot_data(daily_returns, title="Daily returns", ylabel="Daily returns")
print daily_returns.head()

daily_returns.replace(to_replace=np.inf, value=np.NaN, inplace=True)
# Plot a histogram
daily_returns.hist(bins=21)
plt.show()

# Get mean as standard deviation
mean = daily_returns.mean()
std = daily_returns.std()

print mean
print std

#the problem comes here  
plt.axvline(mean, color='w', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
```

[image]

The error is in dataextract.py of my repository on [github](https://github.com/harindersingh/MachineLearningUsingPython)

I have gone through this [link](https://github.com/JosPolfliet/pandas-profiling/issues/) too but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: looks like your `mean` is not a `float`, but a `pandas` `Series`. Check what value you are returning from `daily_returns.mean()`

Comment: @tom the values returned from `code`daily_returns.mean()`code` and `code`daily_returns.std()`code` is float64

Comment: just one `float`, or a `Series` of floats? If `daily_returns` is a `DataFrame`, then `.mean()` will return a `Series` with the mean of each column. `axvline` can't handle that - you would need to loop over the `Series` and plot an `axvline` for each item

Comment: @tom you can see in the snapshot that just after printing `daily_returns.head()` the output for `mean` and `std` is there which says dtype: float64

Comment: So, `mean` = `bitcoin-marker-price   1.006599` ? That to me looks like a 1-item Series, not a float

Comment: Try using `mean[0]` when you plot the `axvline`

Comment: @tom for `print mean` , the output is `bitcoin-market-price   1.006599` `dtype: float64` . This doesn't look like that it is a 1-item series. Even if it is how should I proceed?

Comment: see my previous comment for how to proceed. If you `print type(mean)`, it will tell you its a Series. a pure float wouldn't have `bitcoin-market-price` in there.

Comment: @tom thank you so much, it did solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a 1-item Series in `axvline` instead of a float.

The `.mean()` of a `pandas.DataFrame` is a `pandas.Series`, not a float.

In this case, you can fix it by just taking the value stored in the `Series`

```
plt.axvline(mean[0], color='w', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
```